# sending checkboxes value to database in php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, checkbox

I have a table in my page that first two columns of it come from a table in database, and third column is for checkbox, if user know the meaning of the words that are displayed in table, check them
I want to update my table in database in this way: for checked checkbox insert 1 to checking column in table and otherwise insert 0
 how can I get checkbox value and insert it into right row in database
I have this code until now:

```
    <?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
        or die(mysql_error());   
        if (!$con) { 
            die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
        } 
        mysql_select_db("project", $con)
        or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query("select * from words");
        echo "<table border='1'>
           <tr>
              <th>word</th>
              <th>meaning</th>
              <th>checking</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['word'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>". "<div class='hiding' style='display:none'>".$row['meaning']."</div>"."</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                     echo "<input name=\"fahimeh\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"\"> ";
                    echo "</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  }
         echo "</table>";
         mysql_close($con);                        
        ?>
        <button onclick="ShowMeanings()">ShowMeanings</button>
        <button onclick="feedback()">sendfeedback</button>
```

and it is my javascript code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function ShowMeanings(){
        var hidings = document.getElementsByClassName('hiding');
        for (var i=0; i<hidings.length; i++){
        hidings[i].style.display = 'block';
        }

        }
    </script>
```

I dont know how can I write feedback(), and how can I get checkbox value and insert it into right row in database

Comment: To achieve this you'll first need to set different names for each checkbox, or else you don't know which one is which.

Comment: [Here is what you're looking for.](http://amzn.com/1449319262)

Comment: if I want to set ID of each row in database what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This should work :)

```
<?php
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")
        or die(mysql_error());   
        if (!$con) { 
            die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error()); 
        } 
        mysql_select_db("project", $con)
        or die(mysql_error());
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM words");
        echo "<table border='1'>
           <tr>
              <th>word</th>
              <th>meaning</th>
              <th>checking</th>
            </tr>";
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $row['word'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>". "<div class='hiding' style='display:none'>".$row['meaning']."</div>"."</td>";
                    echo "<td>";
                     echo "<input name=\"fahimeh\" type=\"checkbox\" name='" . $row['id'] . "' value=\"\"> ";
                    echo "</td>";
                  echo "</tr>";
                  }
         echo "</table>";
         mysql_close($con);                        
        ?>
        <button onclick="ShowMeanings()">ShowMeanings</button>
        <button onclick="feedback()">sendfeedback</button>
```

Comment: name='checkbox' is not unique for each row
if I want to set name= $row['id'] what can i do?

Comment: echo "<input name=\"fahimeh\" type=\"checkbox\" name='" . $row['id'] . "' value=\"\"> ";